# Round or Floor or Ceiling

Tags: t-sql

I am trying a number of combinations in order to get to "the next highest number starting with 0" from a particular integer.

I've tried ROUND, CEILING and FLOOR and I can not get any of them to work.

Examples.

```
17 = 20
11 = 20
204 = 210
1001 = 1010
107 = 110
```

So basically any value should then return the next 0 valued number AFTER it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming all is int's then you can divide and multiply with 10 to do it

```
(@i+10)/10*10
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ceiling` only works on 10^0 level, you have to divide, then ceiling, then multiply:

`select 10*ceiling(@value/10)`

Comment: That doesn't work as 107 is rounded to 100 - where I would want it to be the next HIGHEST multiple of 10 - so in this case 110.